# DELETE WooCommerce Order data from database

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, query, mysql

I spent some time in my DB trying to figure out how I can clean out some completed order data. Below is the query that I am confident will help remove the data from completed woocommerce orders.

My question is more of a DB Query one:

```
DELETE * FROM wp_post
JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_post.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items ON wp_postmeta.post_id =  wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
WHERE wp_post.post_type = "shop_order" 
AND wp_post.post_status = "wc-completed"
```

When I run the above query I get the following MySQL error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM wp_post
JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_post.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
JOIN wp_wo' at line 1
```

Am I not `JOIN` my WordPress Tables correctly?

This question may be more appropriate for stackoverflow but figured I would try here first.

Below is the correct query string:

```
DELETE wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_woocommerce_order_items, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta FROM 
JOIN wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id, 
wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id,
wp_posts.ID = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = "shop_order" 
AND wp_posts.post_status = "wc-completed"
```

Which fixed the wp_posts not wp_post  and included all of the tables in-between the DELETE and FROM.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution for delete WordPress WooCommerce orders with SQL:

```
DELETE wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_woocommerce_order_items, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items ON wp_posts.ID = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = "shop_order" 
AND wp_posts.post_date < '2019-03-01';
```

Maybe you should edit the table prefixes (wp_) and the date at the last line.

Comment: This answer did the job for me to delete all orders prior to a specific date

Comment: if you have more then 1 million Orders i recommend adding another AND clause to go between dates since this query will delete exponential records

Answer (score 2):

Try `wp_posts` instead of `wp_post`.

Comment: Thanks @mzykin that was one of my issues. I also had to list all of the tables that are going to have rows removed in-between DELETE and FROM. Those two fixes cleared up my error and the query ran successfully .